# Handling the EditText send keyboard event for Android API16

Tags: android, events, android-edittext, send

```
import com.example.methanegaszonegeolocater.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
//import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.KeyEvent;                       

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

setUpMapIfNeeded();
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    boolean handled = false;
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
        sendMessage();
        handled = true;
        }
    return handled;
    }
});
}
```

I've taken the above code out of the Android Developers Guide. I have a few errors displayed in Eclipse for the code:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The method setOnEditorActionListener(TextView.OnEditorActionListener) in the type     

TextView is not applicable for the arguments (new OnEditorActionListener(){})

- OnEditorActionListener cannot be resolved 
 to a type
```

and:

```
            The method onEditorAction(TextView, int, KeyEvent) of type new OnEditorActionListener(){} must override or implement a supertype method
```

I am at this point trying to determine the cause of the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the line

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
```

to

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
```

or import the statement

```
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;
```

Let me know if this works.